# set two different type checkbox color in the form using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sl.No</th>
                        <th> All </th>
                        <th>Regno.</th>
                        <th>Name</th>    

                  <!--<?php  echo "Core Subjects" ?> -->

                      <?php

                      foreach($getsubc as $rowc)

                      {
                        ?>

                        <td align="center">
                          <?php echo $rowc['subcode']; ?>
                          <input type="checkbox" id="check-all" onClick="toggle(this,<?php echo $rowc['markid']; ?>)" value="<?php echo $rowc['markid']; ?>" checked="checked" data-checkbox-class="icheckbox_square-green">
                      </td>


                      </div>
                      <?php
                      }

                      ?>
                      <!--  Elective subjects -->
                      <?php
                      foreach($getsube as $rowe)
                      {
                        ?>

                        <td align="center">
                          <?php echo $rowe['subcode']; ?> 
                          <input type="checkbox" id="check-all2" onClick="toggle(this,<?php echo $rowe['markid']; ?>)" value="<?php echo $rowe['markid']; ?>" data-checkbox-class="icheckbox_square-blue">
                      </td>


                      <?php

                      }?>


                                              </tr>
                                          <?php

                                    $sno=1;
                                    foreach($getstud as $row)

                                    {

                                      echo '<tr>'; ?>


                                    <?php
                                      echo '<td>'.$sno++.'</td>';

                                      echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['regno'] . '" name="regno[]"></td>';
                                      echo '<td>'.$row['regno'].'</td>';
                                      echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>'; 

                                     ?>

                                     <?php  ?>

                                     <?php  foreach($getsubc as $row1)


                                       {?>

                       <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" data-checkbox-class="icheckbox_square-green" name="friend_id[]"
                                      value="<?php echo $row1['markid'];?>" >


                                      </td>
                                      </td>
                                      </div>


                                       </td>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>

                                     <?php 
                                        } ?>


                                         <?php 




                      foreach($getsube as $row2)
                                       {

                                         ?>


                                         <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" data-checkbox-class="icheckbox_square-blue"   name="friend_id[]" value="<?php echo $row2['markid']; ?>" /> </td>

                                      <?php
                                    }

                                      echo '</tr>';

                                    }
                                    ?>

                                        </table>


                      <script src="<?= base_url('assets/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js') ?>"></script>

                      $('input:checkbox').iCheck({
                          increaseArea: '25%' // optional
                      });
                      </script>


                      <script language="JavaScript">
                        function toggle(source, markid) {
                                checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(markid);
                                for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                                    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
                                }
                        }
                      </script>
```

i changes the code accordingly your solution . but not working both color and select_all method . whats wrong with this code
i changes the code accordingly your solution . but not working both color and select_all method . whats wrong with this code

i changes the code accordingly your solution . but not working both color and select_all method . whats wrong with this code

Comment: which of the checkboxes do you want to apply the green and blue?

Comment: first set of checkboxes to green

Comment: second set of checkboxes to blue

Comment: ok... see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `iCheck` initialization to this:

```
$('input:checkbox').iCheck({
    increaseArea: '25%' // optional
});
```

Then do this on first set:

```
<td align="center">
    <?php echo $row1['subcode']; ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-all" onClick="toggle(this,<?php echo $row1['markid']; ?>)" value="<?php echo $row1['markid']; ?>" checked="checked" data-checkbox-class="icheckbox_square-green">
</td>
```

And then on your second set:

```
<td align="center">
    <?php echo $row2['subcode']; ?> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-all2" onClick="toggle(this,<?php echo $row2['markid']; ?>)" value="<?php echo $row2['markid']; ?>" data-checkbox-class="icheckbox_square-blue">
</td>
```

Notice the use of `data-checkbox-class` attribute on each of the `input:checkbox` tags. Which you can apply the same on the ones within data tables.

Comment: @kvr, have you loaded the `square-green` and `square-blue` skins? these are the CSS and Images needed for rendering which can be found on the `skins/square/` folder of iCheck package.

Comment: path C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin-Panel\assets\plugins\iCheck\square

Comment: css file blue.css,green.css & blue.png,green.png

Comment: ok... make sure you load the blue and green skin styleheets on your page. for example: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">`, and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/iCheck/square/green.css">`.

Comment: in my header file i added.

Comment: still doesn't work? what version is your iCheck? where did you initialize iCheck before the `<table>` or after?

Comment: I put all style sheet and bootstrap and theme and also this css file also